# if $\{a_{n}\}\in C_{0}(Q)$ and $\{b_{n}\}\in C(Q)$ then $\{a_{n}\cdot b_{n}\}\in C_{0}(Q)$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose that we have $C_{0}(Q)=\{f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}:(\forall\epsilon>0)(\exists N\in\mathbb{N})(\forall m>N)(|f(m)|<\epsilon)\}$ and we have $C(Q)=\{f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}:(\forall\epsilon>0)(\exists N\in\mathbb{N})(\forall m,n>N)(|f(m)-f(n)|<\epsilon)\}$ and we want to show that if $\{a_{n}\}\in C_{0}(Q)$ and $\{b_{n}\}\in C(Q)$ it holds that $\{a_{n}\cdot b_{n}\}\in C_{0}(Q)$.

I have looked at the problem, and I think it can be solved using the Triangle Inequality.

We have that, $|a_{m}-a_{n}|<\epsilon_{1}$ and that $|b_{n}|<\epsilon_{2}$ and arrived at the idea that$|a_{m}-a_{n}|+|b_{n}|<\epsilon_{1}+\epsilon_{2}$ and since$|a_{m}-a_{n}+b_{n}|<(|a_{m}-a_{n}|+|b_{n}|)$ then it must be that $|a_{m}-a_{n}+b_{n}|<\epsilon_{1}+\epsilon_{2}$. From here the idea  is to after manipulation extract a $|a_{n}\cdot b_{n}|$ on the right side and gain some insight into the form of $\epsilon_{1}$ and $\epsilon_{2}$ such that $\epsilon_{1}+\epsilon_{2}=\epsilon$ and $|a_{n}\cdot b_{n}|<\epsilon$. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Sequences in $C(Q)$ are Cauchy, hence converge, hence are bounded. What can you say about a bounded sequence times a sequence going to $0?$